# Numbering a "new theorem"

Tags: numbering, theorems, framed, amsthm

I have a (simple?) question. I use the ams `theorem` environment for most of my theorems, but I want to box my definitions and find [here](http://snouffy.free.fr/blog-en/index.php/post/2010/01/30/Nice-boxes-for-your-theorems-with-tikz) a nice way to do it, simpler for me than `mdframed`. My problem is I want the numbering of the theorems to be consistent with each other.

More precisely, here is my preamble about the theorem :

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Th\'eor\`eme}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemme}[thm]{Lemme}
\theorembodyfont{\rmfamily}
\newboxtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemme}
\newboxedtheorem[thcounter=thm,titleboxcolor = white]{defn}{D\'efinition}{thcounter}
```

Then I tried to change the counter `thcounter` to `thm`, or similar, but it didn't work.

Does anybody have any idea of how I can do so that the numbering of my definitions follows the ones of my theorems, lemma...

Comment: Could you include a MWE.  I don't know what packages your working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After following your link I notice the following about what you're trying to do.

- The first optional argument seems to be used for setting and defining `tikZ` styles for the theorem box.
- The first argument is not where you define a new counter.  You can define a new counter in the 4th argument.

So the arguments seem to be as follows:

- The first is optional and used for setting `tikZ` parameters and styles.
- the second is for assigning the `environment` name.
- The third is for setting the name of the environment: i.e., **Theorem**, **Definition**, **Corollary** etc.
- The 4th argument is for creating a counter specific to the named environment.

So to get something like what you want try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{boiboites}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, 
                 background=orange!15, 
                 titlebackground=orange!5,
                 titleboxcolor = black]
                 {theo}{Theorem}{thm}

\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=blue, 
                 background=blue!15, 
                 titlebackground=blue!5,
                 titleboxcolor = black]
                 {defn}{Definition}{thm}

\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=red, 
                 background=red!15, 
                 titlebackground=red!5,
                 titleboxcolor = black]
                 {coro}{Corollary}{coro}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theo}[Title for the theorem]
        \TeX\ is obsure.
  \end{theo}

  \begin{defn}[Title for the definition]
        \LaTeX\ is fun.
  \end{defn}

  \begin{coro}[Title for the corollary]
        \LaTeX\ is fun.
  \end{coro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *the numbering of my definitions follows the ones of my theorems,...*  What I've done above is made the `defn` environment use the same counter as `theo`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Is it possible to do this but give an input flag for black and white boxes for b&w printing?

Comment: @masfenix.  "input flag"?  I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you want the color, but if printed to black-and-white a different setting?  You can always use a gray-scale instead of colors.  And I think using `xcolor` you can define your own *color scheme*.  Using `xcolor` and some conditionals you should be able to switch from color to a black-gray-white output.

Comment: @masfenix.  Personally, I find the colors distracting.  That's not to say I don't use them, I do.  But only when I'm modeling something that my students see it their textbooks.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your answer, that's indeed exactly what I wanted. My mistake was to put the name of the counter inside the "options" of the command \newboxedtheorem[thcounter=thm,titleboxcolor = white]{defn}{D\'efinition}{thcounter}